# Setting mod_python's interperter

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

I have mod_python installed on a debian box with python 2.4 and 2.6 installed. I want mod_python to use 2.6 but it is finding 2.4. How can set it to use the other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Python used is set when mod_python is compiled. If you need to use a version other than the default, you'll need to recompile it, or you may be able to find a different package from the repository.